# winform Form becoming non responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I am starting a thread and updating form element but following code is making form unresposive please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

```
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Updates);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Updates()
    {
        try
        {

            while (true)
            {

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        lblTotalImages.Text = AppHelper.GetTotalCount(textBox1.Text).ToString();
                        if (sitename != null)
                        {

                            lblTotalPosted.Text = AppHelper.GetPostedCount(sitename).ToString();
                           // Application.DoEvents();

                        }
                    });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Edit-------
Thanks @Servy for introducing Task Parallel Library i have never used it here is solution i come up with i used timer and task factory
ya for .net 4 without library extension and vs 2010 i have this working perfectly

```
enter code here private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AppHelper.GetTotalCount(textBox1.Text)).ContinueWith(t => lblTotalImages.Text = t.Result.ToString(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        if (sitename != null)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AppHelper.GetPostedCount(sitename)).ContinueWith(t => lblTotalPosted.Text = t.Result.ToString(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());



        }



    }
```

Comment: Post `AppHelper.GetTotalCount` and `AppHelper.GetTotalCount` code.

Comment: hi Sriram thanks
 i have not implemented it yet but both functions return 1;

Comment: `while(true)` and `Thread.Sleep` are a pretty bad combination but even then so your invoke (I believe) is just making your main program's thread constantly just update some text

Comment: Fine, but How long does that method executes? I suspect that method is the culprit. btw You've to use timer rather than infinite loop with a sleep

Comment: `Catch (Exception) {}` is also a pretty big mistake as it simply prevents you from seeing problems. Never do that.

Comment: thanks Dour High Arch and Sriram Sakthivel for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing some sort of long running non-UI operation inside of the call to `Invoke`, which means it's being done in the UI thread.  You should strive to only be updating the UI in the UI thread; ensure that any long running non-UI code is outside of any invocations to the UI thread.

The use of `await` also allows this solution to be written in a much simpler and more effective manor:

```
public async void StartTimer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string text = textBox1.Text;
        lblTotalImages.Text = await Task.Run(() =>
            AppHelper.GetTotalCount(text).ToString());
        if (sitename != null)
        {
            lblTotalPosted.Text = await Task.Run(() =>
                AppHelper.GetPostedCount(sitename).ToString());
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: wao thats cool never used task before this is really helpful!. I did some googling and get more info about task parallel library i will switch to task instead of threads thats magical libray less code as compared to threads thanks for the introducing that Servy

Comment: i have .net 4.0 was unable to compile 
for .net framework 4.0 here is how to use Savy solution
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Comment: @user3546002 It requires C# 5.0.  You can compile it down to .NET 4.0 with an library extension, but you do need to have VS 2012.

Comment: i have update my question with the solution i have so far can you tell me if i am still doing any thing wrong? 
i am still learning that.. thanks

Comment: @user3546002 You're getting the value of a textbox from a non-UI thread, but other than that it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks how to dispose of the task i checked with profiler there are many task withing 10 min and memory usage is upto 1 gb and app crashed with memory exception i tried this 
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AppHelper.GetPostedCount(sitename)).ContinueWith(t =>
{ lblTotalPosted.Text = t.Result.ToString();t.Dispose();gc.Collect();} TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

and it works perfectly 

but don't know if thats the best practice or not